# Изменение списка ArrayList<>, принадлежащего к одной Activity, внутри другой Activity

Tags: java, android

Внутри MainActivity существует список

> `ArrayList<Card> list = new ArrayList<>();`

,который я передаю в EditObjectActivity c помощью Intent:

```
public void createObject(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditObjectActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Card.class.getSimpleName(), list);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Внутри EditObjectActivity я изменяю список, переданный из MainActivity, добавляя туда новый объект:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle list = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert list != null;
        ArrayList<Card> cardList = (ArrayList<Card>) list.getSerializable(Card.class.getSimpleName());
        cardList.add(new Card(newItem.getName(), newItem.getSubtype(), newItem.getInventoryNumber()));
        intent.putExtra(Card.class.getSimpleName(), cardList);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Как изначальный список, хранящийся в MainActivity, приравнять к тому, что было передано через intent?

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта, простой и более правильный.

Простой, вы можете шарить свой список через интент из первой активити во вторую запуская ее с помощью метода startActivityForResult и возвращая измененный список в метод onActivityResult. Но это решение не гибкое, да и вообще я не рекомендую вам им пользоваться.

Второе более сложное. Это хранить ваш список в какой-то сущности которая живёт независимо от ваших активити. Возможно даже в базу данных.